# Download blob images from Azure

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.forms, blob

In Xamarin Forms I'm trying to download blob images from Azure and store locally.  Th code below works, but at the moment all I can do is loop through the names of each image, I'm struggling with the download part.

The second code snippet below shows what I think it should be but I'm unsure what should be passed in to GetBlockBlobReference, or rather where to find this, so basically I want to move on from listing the images to completing the download, can anyone suggest what I need to do?

```
public async Task ProcessAsync()
{
    storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Resx.Apis.BlobStorageDev);

    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(Resx.AppResources.blobContainer);

    BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;
    do
    {
        var results = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null, blobContinuationToken);
        blobContinuationToken = results.ContinuationToken;
        await DownloadAsync(results);
        foreach (IListBlobItem item in results.Results)
        {
            // here we'll check against what's in local, download if needed
            Debug.WriteLine(item.Uri);

        }
    } while (blobContinuationToken != null); 
}
```

the download bit:

```
CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(???);
foreach (var listBlockItem in await cloudBlockBlob.DownloadBlockListAsync(BlockListingFilter.All, null, null, null))
{

}
```

Comment: can't you have a design of showing thumbnails first and download images only when the user clicks it ?

Comment: Not really, it's part of a sync operation, so should automatically download images not currently existing on local

Comment: anyway to answer your question , you should pass the filename  to the block blob reference.

Comment: thanks, I had tried that, I put a break on that line then when resuming the code seems to hang.  Also, if using a filename, would that not be more relevant to DownloadToFileAsync (which I don't seem to have in intellisense) rather than DownloadBlockListAsync?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the path to the blob inside blob container. So if for example full path to blob is "https://youraccount.blob.core.windows.net/container_name/folder1/folder2/file-name.bin" then you need to pass "folder1/folder2/file-name.bin".